# Emote icon copyright or intellectual property

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

I see a nice emote icon(e.g. [this](http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/U8721VM9p9C2v1o6cKJ4qEnGqnE7IoTQgZI-VTdwyTBeimAcIoxXpgK8bPeslY9pPJIvB5IWW2-452kaM8heLSRgleGCprJLwe94ZKYu2OWsW1xw5OYSXTGyFxSGhTGce-78wQIwZZN4J0mmwckXvd8GXZ9jVuKU7-KZ8w/96fx96f)) in the internet and draw a very similar one to use it in my commercial application. Is this legal or does it break the copyright law?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, It breaks copyright law. This is a [derivative work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work) and the right to create derivative works belong to the copyright owner.

Comment: could you please point out to where do I read about this topic in the copyright law?

Comment: @geotavros Look up your country's copyright laws. Or read up the wikipedia page on the Berne Convention: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention

Comment: Are you sure an emoji would meet [the threshold of originality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_of_originality) for copyright law to apply? I doubt most emoji would.